# Greasemonkey cancel Firefox download prompt

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey

I'm using Firefox version 55.0.2

Is it possible to have a Greasemonkey script which will cancel any download prompt that appears on the page?

For example, visit this page and a download popup will automatically appear - https://myaddictive.com/musiques/tiboy-shalla.html?fiche=3044

Similar to this:

[image]

And I'm wondering if a Greasemonkey script can monitor the browser at all times and immediately Cancel any and all such popups. Not sure if it's possible... Is it?

Comment: I would say it's best to not visit sites that spam you with unwanted downloads. It is not possible to do anything about the dialog from an userscript. You could use userscript to prevent the site from starting the download, but I can't tell you without visiting the site, and the site looks too fishy for me to visit it.

Comment: Not visiting such sites is not an option. And it's not just that one site, there are many sites I visit that do that. And they change, so it's not one or the same number of sites I visit that do this, so preventing a site from starting downloads won't work either. I need to disable downloads completely on the browser, or find an automated way to have these download prompts cancelled when they appear.